# Javascript/Jquery after page is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, tumblr

I'm making a Safari extension that easily posts to tumblr by clicking and holding an image. The code is all working fine currently except, tumblr uses an infinite scroll feature on their page (as you scroll, more posts are loaded onto the page using I assume ajax)

For some reason the script doesn't recognise the new posts that are loaded in and the image click handler is never called - any ideas how to fix this?

Extension code:

```
function confirmShare(src) {
var answer = confirm("Add image to queue?\n"+src)
if (answer){
    $('body').append('<iframe class="quickpostframedatasend" height=0 width=0 style="display:none;" src="http://1hype.me/quickpost/saveimage.php?src=' + src + '"></iframe>');
}

}



var timeoutId = 0;

$('img').mousedown(function() {
    src = $(this).attr("src");
    timeoutId = setTimeout('confirmShare(src)', 900);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the jQuery **live** function
http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$("img").live("mousedown", function() {
    src = $(this).attr("src");
    timeoutId = setTimeout('confirmShare(src)', 900);
}).live("mouseup", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}).live("mouseleave", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind only works with elements already in DOM. Try using .live() or .delegate() http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Also, remember to use .die()/.undelegate() as oposite methods, otherwise your requests will multiply.